# Unable to see folders in Hybris HMC

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am not able to see folders inside Hybris HMC . My hybris version is 6.2 Can you please suggest what can be the issue beside this.

I am able to successfully login inside Hybris HMC but not able to see folders inside it

Comment: Have you checked permissions? What kind of troubleshooting have you actually done?

Comment: Can you provide your local.extensions? Also can you show us a screenshot of what you see in your hmc?

Answer (score 0):

Try running System Update with the following options (you may tick project data as well for your HMC specific extensions).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with permissions for accessing the folders, try logging in as admin and then, search for your user id to see what all permissions have been assigned to it. Also open the hmc.xml file from hmc and see if there are any special groups assigned to certain tree items.